# How to perform case-insensitive sorting array of string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sorting, case-insensitive

I have an array of strings I need to sort in JavaScript, but in a case-insensitive way. How to perform this?

Answer (score 545, accepted):

In (almost :) a one-liner

```
["Foo", "bar"].sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
});
```

Which results in

```
[ 'bar', 'Foo' ]
```

While

```
["Foo", "bar"].sort();
```

results in

```
[ 'Foo', 'bar' ]
```

Comment: Do mind that localeCompare's advanced options are not yet supported on all platforms/browsers. I know they are not used in this example, but just wanted to add for clarity. [See MDN for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

Comment: If you're going to involve localeCompare(), you could just use *its* ability to be case-insensitive, e.g.:
`return a.localeCompare(b, 'en', {'sensitivity': 'base'});`

Comment: +1 for not calling `toLowerCase()` when `localeCompare` already does that by default in some cases.  You can read more about the parameters to pass to it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#Parameters

Comment: @Milimetric accord to the referenced page, that feature is not supported by some browsers (eg. IE<11 or Safari). the solution mentioned here is very good, but would still require backporting/polyfill for some browsers.

Comment: @MichaelDyck That's such an inefficient way of doing sorting though. You're calling a (likely) complex function (`localeCompare`) that even takes an object as a parameter. Calling that multiple times per item per sort call is going to make and already expensive operation (sorting) that much slower.

Comment: localeCompare is case sensitive :- ```var items = ["a", "b", "A", "B", "Z", "z"]; items.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)); [ 'a', 'A', 'b', 'B', 'z', 'Z' ]```

Comment: If you have a large array, it makes sense to use `items.sort(new Intl.Collator('en').compare)` for better performance. (See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator).)

Comment: When sorting multiple times, you should reuse the collator: `let collator = new Intl.Collator('en'); items.sort(collator.compare)`

Comment: 2019: [CanIUse](https://www.caniuse.com/#search=localeCompare) shows wide adoption of `localeCompare`, **however** if your data is in English anyway, consider and test the @ron tornambe answer below before deciding. In my tests of 6,000+ items, the `return a.localeCompare(b, 'en', {'sensitivity': 'base'});` method in the comment above is slow af compared to using `toLowerCase()` alone. [YMMV](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ymmv) and this is a **very** dataset dependent opinion. If your data is internationally sourced, you likely MUST use `localeCompare`. _Just test a bit._

Comment: `["Foo", "bar"].sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))` for the one-liner, it will work as desired for most use cases

Answer (score 146):

It is time to revisit this old question.

You should not use solutions relying on `toLowerCase`. They are **inefficient** and simply **don't work** in some languages (Turkish for instance). Prefer this:

```
['Foo', 'bar'].sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, undefined, {sensitivity: 'base'}))
```

Check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) for browser compatibility and all there is to know about the `sensitivity` option.

Comment: Be careful, this is not supported in all javascript engines.

Comment: Seems as if localCompare now is supported by all browsers except that some mobile browser do not support the 2 optional parameters: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#Browser_compatibility

Comment: It looks like `['Foo', 'bar'].sort((a,b) => a.localeCompare(b))` also works

Comment: @Ollie Williams without the locales and options arguments, the locale and sort order used are entirely implementation-dependent

Comment: Documentation for the sensitivity option: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator/Collator#options

Answer (score 66):

```
myArray.sort(
  function(a, b) {
    if (a.toLowerCase() < b.toLowerCase()) return -1;
    if (a.toLowerCase() > b.toLowerCase()) return 1;
    return 0;
  }
);
```

**EDIT:**
Please note that I originally wrote this to illustrate the technique rather than having performance in mind. Please also refer to answer @Ivan Krechetov for a more compact solution.

Comment: This can call `toLowerCase` twice on each string; would be more efficient to stored lowered versions of the string in variables.

Comment: True and thanks. I wrote this with clarity in mind, not performance. I guess I should note that.

Comment: @Jacob To be fair the accepted answer has same basic problem: it can possibly call `.toLowerCase()` multiple times for each item in array. For example, 45 calls to the compare function when sorting 10 items in reverse order. `var i = 0; ["z","y","x","w","v","u","t","s","r","q"].sort(function (a, b) {++i; return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());}); console.log("Calls to Compare: " + i); // i === 45`

Answer (score 43):

ES6 version:

```js
["Foo", "bar"].sort(Intl.Collator().compare)
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator/compare

Answer (score 28):

```
arr.sort(function(a,b) {
    a = a.toLowerCase();
    b = b.toLowerCase();
    if (a == b) return 0;
    if (a > b) return 1;
    return -1;
});
```

Comment: or `return a === b ? 0 : a > b ? 1 : -1;`

Comment: This will likely not work *as intended* for strings that represent numbers. The arithmetic operators will use the semantics of numbers instead of strings. E.g. if we have `["111", "33"]`, we might want it to return `["111", "33"]` because 1 comes before 3 in character code ordering. However, the function in this answer will return `["33", "111"]` because the number `33` is less than the number `111`.

Comment: @AustinDavis `"33" > "111" === true` and `33 > 111 === false`. It works as intended.

Answer (score 16):

You can also use the new [`Intl.Collator().compare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator/compare), per MDN it's [more efficient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#Performance) when sorting arrays. The downside is that it's not supported by older browsers. <strike>MDN states that it's not supported at all in Safari</strike>. Need to verify it, since it states that [`Intl.Collator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator#Browser_compatibility) is supported.

> When comparing large numbers of strings, such as in sorting large arrays, it is better to create an Intl.Collator object and use the function provided by its compare property

```
["Foo", "bar"].sort(Intl.Collator().compare); //["bar", "Foo"]
```

Answer (score 12):

If you want to guarantee the same order regardless of the order of elements in the input array, here is a [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) sorting:

```
myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    /* Storing case insensitive comparison */
    var comparison = a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
    /* If strings are equal in case insensitive comparison */
    if (comparison === 0) {
        /* Return case sensitive comparison instead */
        return a.localeCompare(b);
    }
    /* Otherwise return result */
    return comparison;
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Normalize the case in the `.sort()` with `.toLowerCase()`.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the Elvis operator:

```
arr = ['Bob', 'charley', 'fudge', 'Fudge', 'biscuit'];
arr.sort(function(s1, s2){
    var l=s1.toLowerCase(), m=s2.toLowerCase();
    return l===m?0:l>m?1:-1;
});
console.log(arr);
```

Gives:

```
biscuit,Bob,charley,fudge,Fudge
```

The localeCompare method is probably fine though...

*Note: The Elvis operator is a short form 'ternary operator' for if then else, usually with assignment.*
If you look at the ?: sideways, it looks like Elvis...
i.e. instead of:

```
if (y) {
  x = 1;
} else {
  x = 2;
}
```

you can use:

```
x = y?1:2;
```

i.e. when y is true, then return 1 (for assignment to x), otherwise return 2 (for assignment to x).

Comment: To be pedantic, this isn't the Elvis operator. This is just a basic ternary operator. A true Elvis operator is null-coalescing, e.g., instead of `x = y ? y : z`, you can do `x = y ?: z`. Javascript doesn't have an actual Elvis operator, but you can use `x = y || z` in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers assume that the array contains strings. My method is better, because it will work even if the array contains null, undefined, or other non-strings.

```
var notdefined;
var myarray = ['a', 'c', null, notdefined, 'nulk', 'BYE', 'nulm'];

myarray.sort(ignoreCase);

alert(JSON.stringify(myarray));    // show the result

function ignoreCase(a,b) {
    return (''+a).toUpperCase() < (''+b).toUpperCase() ? -1 : 1;
}
```

The `null` will be sorted between 'nulk' and 'nulm'. But the `undefined` will be *always* sorted last.

Comment: `(''+notdefined) === "undefined"` so it'd sort before "z"

Comment: Guess I should've looked up the definition of `Array.prototype.sort` :| because the part about `(''+notdefined) === "undefined"` *really is* true... which means if you flip the -1 and 1 in the sort function to reverse the order, undefined still sorts to the end. It also needs to be considered when using the comparison function outside the context of an array sort (as I was when I came upon this question).

Comment: And having now pondered that `Array.prototype.sort` definition - couple more comments. First, there's no need for the `(''+a)` - ECMAScript requires `toString()` to be called on elements prior to passing them into compareFn. Second, the fact that `ignoreCase` returns `1` when comparing equal (including equal-but-for-case) strings means the specification doesn't define the result if there are duplicate values (will probably be fine just with some unnecessary swaps occurring, I think).

Comment: @MattW, It seems to me that `undefined` is a special case, which for *any x* x<undefined and x>undefined are **both false**. That `undefined` is always last, is a byproduct of the sort implementation of sort.  I tried to change the (''+a) to simply a, but it fails.  i get `TypeError: a.toUpperCase is not a function`. Apparently `toString` is **not** called prior to calling compareFn.

Comment: Damn my reading is bad today, `toString` only happens when `compareFn` is `undefined` (native sort). The `undefined` handling is not a natural consequence of `<` and `>` though - it's *definitely* the case that the specification of `sort` requires `undefined` to be specially handled before reaching the steps where it would normally either call `compareFn` or do its native comparison.

Comment: Ah, ok, that makes perfect sense. For `undefined` the compareFn is **never called**

Answer (score 2):

```
arr.sort(function(a,b) {
    a = a.toLowerCase();
    b = b.toLowerCase();
    if( a == b) return 0;
    if( a > b) return 1;
    return -1;
});
```

In above function, if we just compare when lower case two value a and b, we will not have the pretty result.

Example, if array is [A, a, B, b, c, C, D, d, e, E] and we use the above function, we have exactly that array. It's not changed anything.

To have the result is [A, a, B, b, C, c, D, d, E, e], we should compare again when two lower case value is equal:

```
function caseInsensitiveComparator(valueA, valueB) {
    var valueALowerCase = valueA.toLowerCase();
    var valueBLowerCase = valueB.toLowerCase();

    if (valueALowerCase < valueBLowerCase) {
        return -1;
    } else if (valueALowerCase > valueBLowerCase) {
        return 1;
    } else { //valueALowerCase === valueBLowerCase
        if (valueA < valueB) {
            return -1;
        } else if (valueA > valueB) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In support of the accepted answer I would like to add that the function below seems to change the values in the original array to be sorted so that not only will it sort lower case but upper case values will also be changed to lower case. This is a problem for me because even though I wish to see Mary next to mary, I do not wish that the case of the first value Mary be changed to lower case.

```
myArray.sort(
  function(a, b) {
    if (a.toLowerCase() < b.toLowerCase()) return -1;
    if (a.toLowerCase() > b.toLowerCase()) return 1;
    return 0;
  }
);
```

In my experiments, the following function from the accepted answer sorts correctly but does not change the values.

```
["Foo", "bar"].sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
});
```

Comment: how would we do a reverse() case-insensitive?

Answer (score 0):

This may help if you have struggled to understand:

```
var array = ["sort", "Me", "alphabetically", "But", "Ignore", "case"];
console.log('Unordered array ---', array, '------------');

array.sort(function(a,b) {
    a = a.toLowerCase();
    b = b.toLowerCase();
    console.log("Compare '" + a + "' and '" + b + "'");

    if( a == b) {
        console.log('Comparison result, 0 --- leave as is ');
        return 0;
    }
    if( a > b) {
        console.log('Comparison result, 1 --- move '+b+' to before '+a+' ');
        return 1;
    }
    console.log('Comparison result, -1 --- move '+a+' to before '+b+' ');
    return -1;


});

console.log('Ordered array ---', array, '------------');


// return logic

/***
If compareFunction(a, b) is less than 0, sort a to a lower index than b, i.e. a comes first.
If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating back to at least 2003) respect this.
If compareFunction(a, b) is greater than 0, sort b to a lower index than a.
***/
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ianjamieson/wmxn2ram/1/

Answer (score -1):

I wrapped the top answer in a polyfill so I can call .sortIgnoreCase() on string arrays

```
// Array.sortIgnoreCase() polyfill
if (!Array.prototype.sortIgnoreCase) {
    Array.prototype.sortIgnoreCase = function () {
        return this.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: Please never ever do this. Only modify the prototype of things you own. This is also not a polyfill, as this Array method is nowhere in the ECMAScript specs.

Answer (score -3):

Wrap your strings in `/ /i`. This is an easy way to use regex to ignore casing

Comment: The question is about sorting, not matching.