# Sorting in drop down list in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am little bit confuse on how to apply sorting on dropdownlist in jquery

e.g apple,cat,truck,APPLE,CAT,TRUCK

it should be like in drop down list....
apple
APPLE
cat
CAT
truck
TRUCK

how to achieve this in jquery so that it could see the uppercase and lowercase as well.

Comment: I think this could help you http://javascript.about.com/library/blsort1.htm

Comment: Take a look at the answers for this Stack Overflow question: ["How to perform case insensitive sorting in Javascript?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996963/how-to-perform-case-insensitive-sorting-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Lowering the case of items of array in custom sort method  as below [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7AMsf/1/)

```
var arr= [  "apple","cat","truck","APPLE","CAT","TRUCK"];

arr.sort(sort);
function sort(a, b){

   if(a.toLowerCase() > b.toLowerCase()) return 1;
       if(a.toLowerCase() < b.toLowerCase()) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```