# I don't understand how the sort method work in this case, I think it work alphabitticaly but the "aaaa" word in the ray is not..why?

Tags: javascript, sorting, methods

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>
<body>    
  <p id="demo">Click the button to sort the array.</p>  
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>  
  <script>
  function myFunction()
  {    
    var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango","aaaa"];
    fruits.sort();
    var x=document.getElementById("demo");
    x.innerHTML=fruits;
  }    
  </script>    
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: maybe because upper-case letters are sorted before lower case letters (eg order goes:  A, B, C, ..., X, Y, Z, a, b, c, ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sorting is done using the `charCode` of the characters in the string. The UTF8 and ASCII tables have the uppercase letters before the lowercase letters:

```
"A".charCodeAt(0) == 65
"a".charCodeAt(0) == 97
```

If you want to do a case insensitive order, you can pass a compare function to the `sort` call.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Check out this question:

[How to perform case insensitive sorting in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996963/how-to-perform-case-insensitive-sorting-in-javascript)