# Make first option value null in select menu coming from MySQL database

Tags: javascript, php

I am dumping some results from the database directly into  tag in the html, how I can make the first option value to be null, and after that the database results to be sorted? This way I will have this drop down menu an option to not choose anything from it.

this is my code here:

```
<?php 
    $select = new Users;
    $stmt = $select->selecttema();
    while( $row = $stmt->fetch()){ 
        echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['topic'] . '</option>';
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just

```
echo '<option value="">Select a topic</option>'
```

before the while loop.

Answer (score 3):

actually Juan Pablo had answered the question. i just add something on his answer.
 if you add selected in your option it will be first option and you do not need to add data in value

```
echo '<option selected value="">Select a topic</option>';
```

Answer (score 2):

To make an empty option:

```
<select>
    <option value="">Select</option>
<?php 
    $select = new Users;
    $stmt = $select->selecttema();
    while( $row = $stmt->fetch()){ 
        echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['topic'] . '</option>';
    } 
?>
</option>
```

You're not clear about what this Users object is or how you're fetching data so I'll just assume you're using a mySQL database, in which case you can use  `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE 1 ORDER BY id DESC
```

For instance the above statement will select all users in the `users` database and order them by their `id` in descending order.

To sort the `<select>` options in JS, take a look at [Sort Select Options by Value Attribute Using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20693593/sort-select-options-by-value-attribute-using-jquery) and [Javascript to sort contents of select element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278089/javascript-to-sort-contents-of-select-element)