# In Javascript how do I add a new option into Html Select so inserted based on alphabetical value of text

Tags: javascript, html, select

In Javascript how do I add a new option into Html Select so inserted based on alphabetical value of text ?

So I have this

```
var selectMask = document.getElementById("filenamemasks");
var newmask = document.createElement("option");
newmask.text  = maskName;
newmask.value = maskMask;
selectMask.add(newmask);
```

but I want it to add newmask so it comes just after the the option that has value of text just alphabetically before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [append option to select menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182772/append-option-to-select-menu)

Comment: HI, i want to insert not append

Comment: [`.prepend()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend) @PaulTaylor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So building on Mohammads answer and the answer I linked to the solution I found that worked was just to

Add the new element to the end of the list
,then sort list as follows:

```
sortAlphabetically("#filenamemasks");

function sortAlphabetically(selectName) {
     var functionsToSort = $(selectName + ' ' + 'option');
     functionsToSort.sort(function(a,b){
        var textA = a.text.toUpperCase();
        var textB = b.text.toUpperCase();
        return (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0;
     });
     $(selectName).html(functionsToSort); 
}
```

Comment: your answer is shorter but you said in Javascript . and I thought you don't want to use any third-party library. but it's great.

Answer (score 2):

You have to get all options and add theme to and array variable called `options`. Second add new item to `options` array and the sort that array and clear select tag and at the end add sorted `options` to select tag like this.

```js
      
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click',function(event){
        var options = [];
        var selectMask = document.getElementById("filenamemasks");
        var newmask = document.createElement("option");
        newmask.text  = document.getElementById('option_title').value;
        newmask.value = document.getElementById('option_value').value;
        options.push(newmask)
        var i;
        var txt;
        for (i = 0; i < selectMask.length; i++) {
         options.push(selectMask.options[i]);
            txt = txt + "\n" + selectMask.options[i].text;
        }
        options.sort(function(a, b) {
            var textA = a.text.toUpperCase();
            var textB = b.text.toUpperCase();
            return (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0;
        });
        
        selectMask.innerHtml="";
        for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            selectMask.add(options[i]);
        }
      });
```

```html
        <select id="filenamemasks">
        <option value="1">Apple</option>
        <option value="2">Banana</option>
        <option value="3">Mango</option>
        <option value="4">Orange</option>
    </select>
    <input id="option_title" placeholder="title">
    <input id="option_value" placeholder="value">
    <button id="button">add item</button>
```

Comment: Okay thanks, shame there is not a way to just insert in place instead though. SO I couldnt apply a sort() function directly to the select then ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor, I think there is no easier way in javascript. maybe using a third-party library.

Comment: Okay, fair enough.

Comment: Actually likes yo can sort a select, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51670552/in-javascript-how-do-i-add-a-new-option-into-html-select-so-inserted-based-on-al/51671626?noredirect=1#comment90330600_51671626

Comment: Sorry I meant - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20693593/sort-select-options-by-value-attribute-using-jquery