# JavaScript's sort method handling of capital letters

Tags: javascript

Noticed something potentially odd with JavaScript's `sort()` method. Given the following array:

```
var arr = ['Aaa',
'CUSTREF',
'Copy a template',
'Copy of Statementsmm',
'Copy1 of Default Email Template',
'Copy11',
'Cust',
'Statements',
'zzzz'];
```

Calling sort on this array:

`console.log(arr.sort());`

Yields:

```
["Aaa", "CUSTREF", "Copy a template", "Copy of Statementsmm", "Copy1 of Default Email Template", "Copy11", "Cust", "Statements", "zzzz"]
```

Is this correct? ie. `CUSTREF` is listed first, is this because of it's capital letters?

Comment: That's how [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) works. Characters are sorted by their Unicode values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to perform case insensitive sorting in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996963/how-to-perform-case-insensitive-sorting-in-javascript)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That is correct. The strings are being sorted in a binary fashion, using the ordinal values of the characters themselves.

For a case-insensitive sort, try this:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b) {
    a = a.toLowerCase();
    b = b.toLowerCase();
    if( a == b) return 0;
    return a < b ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: Okay... which two chumps downvoted this answer just now, and why?

Answer (score 14):

You are correct, it is because of capital letters. If you are sorting strings which might have non ASCII characters such as ä and ö you should use [String.localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare). This also fixes the capital letter problem.

```
arr.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.localeCompare(b);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes,
It has a higher Unicode value. (it = the 'U' in the first word)

you maybetter use

`.sort(function(a,b) { return (a.toLowerCase() < b.toLowerCase()) ? -1 : 1;});`

Comment: WRONG. The sort function must return a *number*, not a boolean.

Comment: + missing arguments `a` and `b`.

Comment: @Teemu Pfft, that too. The boolean return was so blinding to me that I completely missed the missing arguments! XD

Answer (score 0):

if you look at they way characters are encoded (eg. ASCII table) you will see, that capital letters have lower values that lowercase one's, so yes - it's because of capital letters

Answer (score 0):

Since `U` (U+0055) has a lesser Unicode value than `o` (U+006F), a case-sensitive `sort` will always place `U` before `o`. For a case-insensitive `sort`, you should try:

```
arr.sort(
    function(a, b){
        if (a.toLowerCase() < b.toLowerCase()) return -1;
        if (a.toLowerCase() > b.toLowerCase()) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
);
```