# Multi Column Sort on different datatypes

Tags: javascript, sorting, multidimensional-array

Am implementing Sorting on a Multidimensional Object with different columns and my columns are dynamic. Only at Run time i will know how many columns are assigned.

many version on Google. i Liked  the community wiki on https://stackoverflow.com/a/4760279/1481690

But this doesn't work with different data types and case sensitive string. How can i implement for different data types like number , Date , Boolean etc. Including Case insensitive sort.

Also like in the below Array

```
var arr = [
    { id:5, name:"Name3"  , boolean: true, date:2015-03-12},
    { id:4, name:"Name1" ,  boolean: true , date:2015-03-12},
    { id:6, name:"Name2" , boolean: true, date:2015-03-12 },
    { id:6, name:"Name2"  , boolean: null, date:2015-03-12 },
    { id:6, name:"Name2"  , boolean: false, date:2015-03-12 },
    { id:6, name:"Name2"  , boolean: true, date:2015-03-12 },
    { id:2, name:"Name2"  , boolean: false, date:2015-03-12 },
    { id:1, name:"Name2"  , boolean: true, date:2015-03-12 }
];
```

- The date format is converted into number and am  not sure how to handle date ?
- Also Case insensitive Sort
- Handling All data types

Please suggest..
Thanks

Comment: Your "*dates*" are arithmetic expressions.

Comment: @PM77-1 How do i handle that in my scenario ?

Comment: Use [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object constructor.

Comment: @PM77-1 Thanks  let me try this..how ab for case insensitive ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996963/how-to-perform-case-insensitive-sorting-in-javascript