# javascript sort method not running on array[1]

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, methods

```
var test = ['hello', 'Hello']
var arg1 = test[0].split('').sort().join('').toLowerCase();  // ehllo
var arg2 = test[1].split('').sort().join('').toLowerCase();  // hello
```

Would someone be able to explain why the sort method appears to have no effect on the 2nd element of the test array?

Comment: `"H" < "e" === true`

Comment: `test[1].toLowerCase().split('').sort().join('');` should work. You are sorting then transforming.

Comment: convert to lower case first and then compare elements

Comment: using toLowerCase() before the sort did the trick. Thank you for the great replies! Sorry I didn't find the previous thread on the subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to ignore case, you should lowercase before sorting:

```js
console.log('Hello'.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join('')); // ehllo
```

Answer (score 8):

```js
console.log('H' < 'e', 'H'.charCodeAt(0), 'e'.charCodeAt(0));
```

Capital letters range from 65 to 90. Lower case letters range from 97 to 122. String comparisons are based on character codes.

Consider being more explicit with your sort by using a custom function.

Answer (score 2):

This question was answered in StackOverflow before [case insensitive sorting in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9645447/812519)

```
'Hello'.split('').sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
}).join('');
```

If you care to have a case sensitive output e.g. `Hello` would become `eHllo`