# Case insensitive sort using vaadin-grid

Tags: polymer, vaadin-grid

I am using vaadin-grid component for a view where I am showing some grid data including text. In the columns of text, sorting doesn't seem to be case insensitive. Sorting happens only with the text starting with Capital letters and the ones starting with small letters are being ignored.
I checked the [API documentation](https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-components/preview/vaadin-grid/demo/sorting-filtering.html) of vaadin-grid-sorter which is a helper element for sort in vaadin-grid but could not get the desired result.
    Please suggest some other way round. Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always sort your dataset manually, before setting it as the grid's `items`.

For how to implement case-insensitive sorting take a look at:
[How to perform case insensitive sorting in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996963/how-to-perform-case-insensitive-sorting-in-javascript)

EDIT:
If you're using a (remote API) dataProvider (see https://vaadin.com/elements/vaadin-grid/html-api/elements/Vaadin.GridElement: Lazy Loading with Function Data Provider), your provider function will be called with a `callback` function as its second parameter, after the request completes. Just sort your results before passing them to that callback.

Comment: We are not using GridElement. Currently data is coming from some static json file.

Comment: Vaadin.GridElement is just <vaadin-grid/>. It rather depends on whether you are using the attribute `items` or `dataProvider` for displaying data.

Answer (score 1):

With Vaadin 14(.1.25) you can sort case insensitive e.g. with this:

```
Column<MyObject> column = ...;
column.setComparator(new Comparator<MyObject>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyObject arg0, MyObject arg1) {
        return arg0.getText().compareToIgnoreCase(arg1.getText());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
container.setItemSorter(new CaseInsensitiveItemSorter());
```

That should be all you need - for Vaadin 7 or 8 at least, not sure about 10.