# Sort() doesn’t work correctly for Alphabetical List

Tags: javascript, sorting, ionic3

I’m using `sort()` method for making Alphabetical List but it seems not working correctly
that's an example of data  I'm getting

`address: " P.O. BOX : 3625, POSTAL CODE : 112, RUWI.  ABOVE ELITE JEWELLERY SHOP BUILDING, 2ND"
area_id: "27"
area_name: "Ruwi"
city_name: "Muscat"
clinic_hours: "SAT-THU 9:00AM to 1:00PM 5:00PM to 9:00PM,FRI  CLOSED"
hosp_id: null
hospital_name: null
id: "132"
insurance_companies: "None"
lat: "23.59032790"
longi: "58.54473540"
name: " AL WARDAH MEDICAL & DENTAL CLINIC"
phone: "24832011"
services: " GENERAL MEDICINE, GYNAECOLOGY, EYE, ENT, SKIN, PAEDIATRICS.,GENERAL DENTAL CARE & SERVICES."
spec: "Dentistry,General Practitioner"
spec_id: "70,75"`

here is the code

`// sorting data
      this.Clinics = Data.sort(function(a, b){
        return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
      })`

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzRs0.png)

Comment: post your list with code specifically `Data` that you're trying to sort

Comment: That image doesn't tell us that the rendered data is the sorted data or that the `name` is what is shown. Please provide a runnable [mcve] that reproduces the issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform case-insensitive sorting in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996963/how-to-perform-case-insensitive-sorting-in-javascript)

Comment: the data I'm getting an group objects form restful API .. I updated the question with an example of data I'm getting

Comment: Schema of your response data would be more beneficial than a snapshot of what I assume is a single entry.  I also notice your example data doesn't trim white space, something you'd probably also want to when comparing, or when cleansing your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localeCompare` by default is case sensitive, capital letters come before lowercase.

[localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

You can pass an options object that sets the compare to `base` so `a==A` but that also requires the locale,

```
return a.name.localeCompare(b.name, 'en', {'sensitivity': 'base'});
```

or you can manually `toLowercase` or `toUppercase` your strings within the compare function

```
return a.name.toLowercase().localeCompare(b.name.toLowercase());
```

This is where sanitizing your data before storing or rendering it comes in handy, but the above will get you by if you have zero control over the source.