# Google Scripts - Sorting but without being case sensitive

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, alphabetical-sort

I am writing an Google Scripts attached to Google Form and Google Sheet. I have a list of names where some have entered the data with lower case and upper case. I am trying to sort - however, the standard .sort() is sorting the Upper Case first and then the lower case - which is very confusing.

Could you suggest how i can sort a data so that it doesn't take into account the case for sorting - but retains the original uppwer and lower cases.

For e.g. var  a = {Charlie, alpha, delta, Bravo};

Desired output {alpha, Bravo, Charlie, delta}.

Thank you.

Regards, 
ray

Comment: P.S - I have tried using the .toLowerCase etc.. but that doesn't seem to work in google scirpts

Comment: Repeat of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996963/how-to-perform-case-insensitive-sorting-in-javascript

Comment: You can just about anything you want with a custom sorting function read about it on MDN

Answer (score 2):

You can define a custom function in javascript sort.
eg:

```
var a = ["Charlie", "alpha", "delta", "Bravo"];
a = a.sort(function(x, y){
      x = x.toLowerCase()
      y = y.toLowerCase()
      if (x < y) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (x > y) {
        return 1;
      }
       return 0;
    })
// Outputs [ "alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "delta" ]
```