# JavaScript case insensitive sorting for HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

How I just want to implement Case - Insensitive Sort in this Javascript code for my Table.
How can this be possible?

Please see below:

```
cPrev = -1; 
            
function sortBy(c) {
    rows = document.getElementById("data_table").rows.length; 
    columns = document.getElementById("data_table").rows[0].cells.length; 
    arrTable = [...Array(rows)].map(e => Array(columns)); 
    for (ro=0; ro<rows; ro++) {
        for (co=0; co<columns; co++) {
            arrTable[ro][co] = document.getElementById("data_table").rows[ro].cells[co].innerHTML;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: So use toLowerCase()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do case insensitive string comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140627/how-to-do-case-insensitive-string-comparison)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996963/how-to-perform-case-insensitive-sorting-array-of-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function works to sort strings alphabetically and places uppercase before lowercase.

```
function (a, b) {
   var x = String(a).toLowerCase(); 
   var y = String(b).toLowerCase(); 
     
   if (x > y) 
     return -1;
   if (x < y) 
     return 1; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it case insensitive just use .toLowerCase() or .toUpperCase()

```
document.getElementById("data_table").rows[ro].cells[co].innerHTML.toUpperCase()
```